# How to deal with the error of PyDev's unzip importing in Eclipse Mars4.5

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-mars

At first, I tried installing PyDev by URL in Eclipse. but it didn't work.
Also, I tried moved unzip PyDev into dropin directory of Eclipse, but it didnt work  and said "org.python.pydev.debug.newcosole.prefs.interactionConsolePrefs cannot be found by org.python.pydev.debug_5.2.0.qualifier".

What does it mean? and What should I do?

Also, I was said "
Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.python.pydev (542)."

Comment: I guess Eclipse Mars (4.5) is too old. Does it work with Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9)?

Comment: The [PyDev site](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) says "PyDev requires Java 8 and Eclipse **4.6** (Neon)". So Mars is too old.

Comment: @greg-449
Thx 4 your comment.

I knew that and also intend to try it later. Did you read about massage(like a direction) of Older version one? →
Need to use older Eclipse/Java/Python
If you need to use an older version of Eclipse/Java/Python, below is the latest PyDev version to be used based on your requisites.

Eclipse 4.5, Java 8: PyDev 5.2.0
Eclipse 3.8, Java 7: PyDev 4.5.5

I can't understand the reason why PyDev doesn't work when Eclipse is too old.